# Azure Databricks - How to dynamically read the new file from the mount point?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

i have below mount point created

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/mount/raw2")
```

and have below file available in the above mount point

```
customer1.csv
| ID|  Name| Place|
+---+------+------+
|101|  Hari|   Tcr|
|102|  John|   Bgr|
```

now i am reading the file into the dataframe

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/mnt/mount/raw2")
```

this read the customer1.csv file

now i am writing this into the delta table

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/mount/raw2/customer_data")
```

then i recieve new data in the mount point

```
customer2.csv with 
103|Stefen|   Hyd|
|104| Devid|   Bgr|
|105| Wager|London|
```

now i want to append the data into the same delta location - customer_data

so what is the best way to read the new arrived file from the mount location dynamically from the same mount point

so i am looking for scenario as below

```
existing_delta_table =
| ID|  Name| Place|
+---+------+------+
|101|  Hari|   Tcr|
|102|  John|   Bgr|

new arrived file 
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/mnt/mount/raw2")

if df is new_file:
   existing_delta_table.append(df_records)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auto loader` concept.
Follow below steps.

I have used `cutomer1.csv`.

[image]

Next, run below code.

```
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")\
.option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "/checkpoint_path/").load("/mnt/mount/raw2/")

df.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpointLocation/").format("delta").trigger(availableNow=True)\
  .start("/mnt/mount/raw2_customer_data").awaitTermination()
```

Here you need to give delta table path different from source.

[image]

Now, the data in delta table is.

[image]

Next, adding `cutomer2.csv` now.

[image]

Again, run above code. Which checks for new file and update the records.

[image]

and in table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jayashankar.. Is this same approach for data upsert? And once after we deployed the databricks job, will it check the new incoming file arrived in the source without a event notification?

Comment: For upsert you can do delta merge. Whenever you run it checks the processed files in checkpoint based on that it will load data.

Comment: Are you referring to use below delta merge approach
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/merge#python'

Comment: Yeah. update when matched and insert for unmatched records.